# Check programmatically version of magento by entering URL

Tags: magento

I want to know how can we check programmatically the version of magento  being used without having any access to either ftp or admin.
Ex url http://magentoversion.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess,

Get the [contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) of `css/styles.css` or some other `js` file and check for,

> @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc.
>   (http://www.magentocommerce.com)

E.g.,

```
Version             @copyright
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Magento 1.9         Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
Magento 1.8         Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
Magento 1.7         Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
Magento 1.6         Copyright (c) 2011 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
Magento 1.4.1-1.5   Copyright (c) 2010 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
Magento 1.4.0       Copyright (c) 2009 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
Magento 1.0-1.3     Copyright (c) 2008 Irubin Consulting Inc. DBA Varien (http://www.varien.com)
```

Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/62966/2206

**UPDATE:**

Code to get the content and search for a particular string and return the line is as follows,

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.magentosite.com/skin/frontend/base/default/css/widgets.css';//or which ever you feel to take
$data = get_data( $url );
$string = "@copyright";
$data   = explode("\n", $data);

for ($line = 0; $line < count($data); $line++) {
    if(strpos($data[$line], $string)){
        echo $data[$line];
    }
}

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you give me any specific code snippet to read only copyright info.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt, that is purely a PHP/javascript stuff :). Will post if I get

Comment: Ok will try but please help if you get it.

Comment: Please find an update. See several other ways to perform the same tasks and that also depend on server configuration also. Whichever you like idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you shouldn't really be able to access the version on a well configured server. The site you linked to uses /downloader and RELEASE_NOTES.txt but these would (or at least should) be removed or denied on a production site and wouldn't work in those cases. Beyond that, you could try calculating the hash of various core files that are accessible to the public (namely the Mage JS files) and see if there are enough changes across versions so that they could be treated as a lookup table for the site you're examining.